# how 'telerik.grid.filtering.min.js' works in a grid

Tags: filtering, telerik-grid

Can anyone please tell how `telerik.grid.filtering.min.js` works? How does telerik invoke it? Can a programmer take control on it through coding.

Comment: That's a little bit broad...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tell us more about what you're doing and what you want to achieve in order to provide more helpful answers.

But basically you would have to include *telerik.grid.filtering.min.js* in your page and use the filtering methods/properties according to [the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid).

Comment: My Question is whether telerik internally calls telerik.grid.filtering.min.js in case of filtering in a grid, i haven't included telerik.grid.filtering.min.js in my project, but the filtering works, so i want to know whether telerik.grid.filtering.min.js is called internally by the telerik if filtering is used, I am not using Kendo UI.

Comment: Ok. You may want to update your question to include that information, you are being downvoted because it is so unspecific. If the filtering works then you probably don't need the file. I guess it is only used for certain things that you aren't using - or you're including a file that contains all the modules combined into one, something like *telerik.all.min.js*?

Comment: I have only included jquery-1.6.4.min.js in my project, I haven't used telerik.all.min.js, so whether jquery-1.6.4.min.js is handling all the jQuery scripts and JavaScript files.